# Split command give {} in expect language

Tags: split, tcl, expect

I have file with host entry list. I am trying to use below split command to make as a single line: `set host-list [split file "\n"]`

It is giving me the extra `{}` which I don't require.

The file has,  for example,  below entries:

- 12.22.33.44 test.com
- 12.44.55.55 test2.com

Run:

```
set host-list [split file "\n"]
```

Output:

```
12.22.33.44 test.com   12.44.55.55 test2.com {}
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because the last character in a "text" file is the newline on the file's last line. Then, when you split on newlines, you get the empty string following the trailing newline.

This is where `read -nonewline` comes in handy.

`string trimright` also comes to mind.